# Using indexed array elements as integration dummy variables with EvaluationMonitor. Bug?

Tags: numerical-integration, bugs, list-manipulation, monitoring, index

**Bug introduced in 8.0.4 or earlier and fixed in 11.1**

---

As part of a routine that must cope with integration of varying numbers of dimensions, I would like to use indexed variable names (e.g., `x[0]`, `x[1]`,...) as dummy integration variables. However, it doesn't work correctly. Here are simplified examples that highlights the problem:

```
NIntegrate[1, {x0, 0, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print["hi"]]
```

and

```
NIntegrate[1, {x0, 0, 1}, {x1, 0, 1 - x0}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print["hi"]]
```

work correctly (i.e., integrate correctly and print `"Hi"` at each step of integration),

```
NIntegrate[1, {x[0], 0, 1}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print["hi"]]
```

also works correctly.

However,

```
NIntegrate[1, {x[0], 0, 1}, {x[1], 0, 1 - x[0]}, EvaluationMonitor :> Print["hi"]]
```

integrates correctly but does not trigger the `EvaluationMonitor`.

What is the problem?

Comment: Reported to the developers as a bug. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been fixed in the [just released](http://blog.wolfram.com/2017/03/16/the-rd-pipeline-continues-launching-version-11-1/) Mathematica 11.1.

```
NIntegrate[1, {x[0], 0, 1}, {x[1], 0, 1 - x[0]}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> Print["hi"]]
```

> hi

< ... >

> hi
>
> ```
> 0.5
> ```